# Distinct the extract month for oracle

Tags: oracle

Below is my query to extract month from date,

```
    Select distinct  Extract (Month From Dates) As Bulan, Count(Matric_No) As Total,Matric_No
    From Stud_Sick
    Group By Matric_No,Dates
    Order By Dates;
```

This give me error 'not a SELECTED expression'. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try and see what happens?

Comment: @Boneist actually i want to it like this, Select distinct  Extract (Month From Dates) As Bulan, Count(Matric_No) As Total,Matric_No
From Stud_Sick
Group By Matric_No,Dates
Order By Dates;

Comment: @Boneist and it give me error ' not a selected expression'

Comment: why distinct and group by ?

Comment: All your data is from one year? Or are you supposed to be counting all the values from, say, May in every year?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're after the following:

```
select extract(month from dates) bulan,
       count(matric_no) as total,
       matric_no
from   stud_sick
group by extract(month from dates),
         matric_no
order by extract(month from dates);
```

---

Or possibly you're after:

```
select extract(month from dates) bulan,
       count(matric_no) as total
from   stud_sick
group by extract(month from dates)
order by extract(month from dates);
```

Comment: it works perfectly. and one more thing, can i SUM the total??

Comment: If it makes sense to do a sum on that column, then yes. Did you try it?

Comment: yes and i just add 'SUM(count(matric_no)) OVER() AS total_count'. the result is i got a new column name total_count.

Comment: Is that what you wanted? If it's not, please update your question to include some sample data along with the output you're expecting to see when your query is run against that sample data.

Comment: it show me the same total_count for five rows because of the different total of matric_no. the result that i want is only the month and the total_count.

Comment: So why group by the matric_no? Remove that column from the select list and the group by, and does that give you the result you're after?

Comment: ok bro. i have remove group by matric_no, and the column count(matric_no) as total. now i get what i want.... thank you very much... really appreciate it.

Comment: "bro" is assuming a lot! *{;-)